# Pass front-end input value to code behind / google federated login

Tags: asp.net, google-plus, hidden-field, google-signin

I tried to use google federated login function to retrieve user info in order to implement an one-click registration functionality for my website.

I have retrieved all the information on the client side. I used several hidden input fields to store the values for the parameters like name,email, etc. However, when I accessed these fields from code behind, **I got empty values**.

Here are the steps I took to inspect the problem:
    1. I have made sure that each input field has the [runat="server"] tag and have made sure that all the values  are correctly returned from google.
    2. I have made sure that all the input fields are inside the form

I am wondering if it is because I did not submit the form once I clicked the google+ login button, the button is as the following:

```
<div id="signin-button" class="slidingDiv">
 <div class="g-signin" data-callback="loginFinishedCallback"
  data-approvalprompt="force"
  data-clientid="....."
  data-scope="  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me "
  data-height="short"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
  >
</div>
</div>
```

This button will lead me to other functions that verify about my credentials and return the parameters I request. I am wondering how I could modify it so that I could make the form be submitted once I click on this button?

If it is not caused by this issue, could anyone think of other possible reasons why I could not get the hidden input value from code behind?

**Here is my callback function**

```
 function loginFinishedCallback(authResult) {
      if (authResult) {
          if (authResult['error'] == undefined) {
              gapi.auth.setToken(authResult); 
              toggleElement('signin-button'); /
              getInfo();

              document.getElementById('Button').click();
          } else {
              console.log('An error occurred');
          }
      } else {
          console.log('Empty authResult');  
      }
  }
```

getInfo will get all the google plus information , and button.click() is supposed to retrieve the information from the client side to the server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google+ Sign-In button currently does not POST form data but instead passes the authorization code and access token back to the page in the callback function configured in the button. You might be able to do something clever like use JavaScript to update a hidden field with the content (which you might already be doing?) and then use the data from that hidden field for OAuth 2 code exchange on your server side.

An alternate approach is used in the [Google+ C# Quick Start sample](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp). What that sample does is use an API endpoint to POST the authorization code that later is exchanged server-side for the OAuth 2 credentials.

I have thrown together [some code that will pass the authorization code for authorizing your backend](https://github.com/gguuss/gplus-quickstart-csharp/tree/forms). It consists of the form frontend:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="fedLogin.aspx.cs"     Inherits="GPlusQuickstartCsharp.fedLogin" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var confirms = 0;
        function loginFinishedCallback(result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (result.access_token != null) {
              gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function(){
                gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
                  gapi.client.plus.people.get({ userId: 'me' }).execute(
                    function (resp) {
                        document.getElementById('name').value = resp.displayName;
                        confirms += 1;
                        if (confirms > 1) {
                            document.getElementById('form1').submit();
                        }
                    });
              });
              gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
                gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(
                    function (resp) {
                        document.getElementById('email').value = resp.email;
                        confirms += 1;
                        if (confirms > 1) {
                            document.getElementById('form1').submit();
                    }
                    });
                  });
                });
                document.getElementById('code').value = result.code;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div id="signin-button" class="slidingDiv">
        <div class="g-signin" data-callback="loginFinishedCallback"
            data-clientid="....apps.googleusercontent.com"
            data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
            data-height="short"
            data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
        >
    </div>
    </div>

    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="code" id="code" />
        <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" />
        <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
</html>
```

And the code behind [C#]:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace GPlusQuickstartCsharp
{
    public partial class fedLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request["code"] != null)
            {
                // Perform code exchange here
                var result = ManualCodeExchanger.ExchangeCode(Request["code"]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If you put a breakpoint at the `var result = ...` line, you can see the request variables in your immediate window, e.g.:

```
Request["code"]
"4/xUgz-_zWFAgpq4Kbfas66pV0oWJ8........."
Request["email"]
"gguuss@gmail.com"
Request["name"]
"Gus Class (Gus)"
```

Hope this helps!

Note: Although you need the client ID and client secret to exchange the one-time-code as demonstrated in the code, it's a best practice to protect it as best you can. I'm using a POST in an effort to protect the code in the form to help but you should also use https whenever you are passing around credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried your method and wonder where I could get ManualCodeExchanger class? The way I implemented this was, I created another hidden button for a function that retrieves information from google+. Upon clicking on the google sign-in button,I added a button.click function in the callback fucntion.the button will be triggered and data can be fetched. My only problem now is that although  I get the feedback data on the client side, I could not get it updated on the server side.I have also tried to added the form.submit function as you stated in the comment, butgot noluck

Comment: In addition, the form I used was not only for these several hidden fields, it actually contains other fields to be submitted as a normal form with another submit button. I am just wondering if it is possible to update part of the form, such as several hidden fields upon the change of values for them.

Comment: The ManualCodeExchanger class is included in the C# quick start sample, if it would help, I can upload the project I used to test this which integrates the C# quick start and a `runat="server"` form.  As far as partially populating multiple forms or populating a form that will be coupled to a code behind goes, there should be no issues. I can try and verify that soon.

Comment: thanks a lot! I will try this tomorrow once I get started working on the project. It would be really helpful if you could also upload the project.

Comment: A final comment, I added a link to a branch of the quick start with a form that passes hidden values set after authorization mixed with regular form fields. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Gus, I got the following error after I imported the class:[The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.] it happens in the line:  WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); I am also wondering where you added the link? I could not find it for some reason.

Comment: The code is at: https://github.com/gguuss/gplus-quickstart-csharp/tree/forms. The link is on "code that I threw together". If you are getting a 400 error, it could be that you haven't setup the client ID and client secret.

Comment: actually I have set up the client id and client secret. I am wondering if filling in the fields of builder.Append("...") in FormPostData() is sufficient enough for them to be set up?

Comment: gplus-quickstart-csharp/gplus-quickstart-csharp/signin.ashx.cs is where ManualCodeExchanger is getting it's ID / secret. Also, you need to set the client ID in fedLogin.ashx. Also, make sure you have turned on the Google+ API in your project.